# Setting fileds from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main page with a div with id="t1", into this div i loaded the content of another html page with

```
$("#t1").load("./page2.html");
```

In my page2 I have paragraph with id as well (id = "text1")
How can I change this field from the js?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any conflicts, then it is placed in the same DOM. You just need to properly wait for it to be loaded:

```
$("#t1").load("./page2.html",function(text,status,jqXHR){
   $("#text1").html("This is the internal we are editing");
});
```

The documentation for it is here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you!it worked
But can you explain a little more about the function - what are those parameters

Comment: Sure. The callback is called after the data is loaded and rendered into the element you listed (in this case `"#t1"`). `text` is the text content of the ajax request that was made to load the data; `status` is the http status of the request; `jqXHR` is the jquery-XHR object that was used to make and receive the response.

Comment: Pleasure. :-) Use it well.